# How can I do a cascading Entity Reference data entry or is it even possible?

Tags: views, entities

I am working on a system where we want users to be able to create a Project which will be made up of one or more Project Activities, each Project Activity being constituted of several Sub-Activities.

Each Project Activity can be one of several types, and the Sub-Activities also are typed. This means that when I assign a Project Activity to a Project, I should only assign Sub-Activities of the same corresponding type.

So, I have two fields in the Project content type, one is Project Activity, the other is Sub-Activity (which can have multiple values). Both these fields are Entity References to the corresponding Project Activity and Sub-Activity content types. What I want then, is when I enter the Project and choose Project Activity type A, I should only be able to select Sub-Activities of type A also.

I had thought to do this using the Views selection with a contextual filter, however this only seems to work with a static filter when mine needs to be dynamic.

Does anyone know a way round this, or a different approach which could solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've not used it yet myself. But, if you want an out of the box solution you can try the [Hierarchial Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module:

> This module defines the "hierarchical_select" form element, which is a
>   greatly enhanced way for letting the user select items in a hierarchy.
>
> Hierarchical Select has the ability to save the entire lineage of a
>   selection or only the "deepest" selection. You can configure it to
>   force the user to make a selection as deep as possible in the tree, or
>   allow the user to select an item anywhere in the tree. Levels can be
>   labeled, you can configure limit the number of items that can be
>   selected, configure a title for the dropbox, choose a site-wide
>   animation delay, and so on. You can even create new items and levels
>   through Hierarchical Select!

See the project page for a Demo page.

Depending on how complex your criteria is you could also consider the [`#states` Form API of Drupal 7](http://randyfay.com/states), or a simple jquery Ajax callback on your select tags in the form.